# SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10 - there was a pr--lem sending the command to the program

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Trying to open a script from explorer and recently started getting this error. 
I can open the script from within SQL Server Management Studio. 
Also noticed this says (Administrator). Hmmm...

I looked at old replies on topic, but they were older versions of SQL Server and Windows and suggestions did not work.

Stumped.

Comment: How about SSMS -> File -> Open file?

Comment: Yes, this works fine. Hoping to resume auto open from directories I use to store my scripts.